# White space on flex column on row hover

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions

My last Column in the below table is using `display-flex` I am not using any padding or margin however, when hovering on the row I get that white space on the last column.

My Last column looks like that:

`<td class="d-flex flex-end">buttons here</td>`

css:

```
.flex-end {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.d-flex {
    padding: 0!important;
    display: flex;
}
```

Here is the code for the row hover:

```
.collection-table tr:hover td {
    background-color: #ffc;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `flex-grow: 1` to the flex child.

Comment: I have added that code in the same class which uses `display:flex`. Am I correct?

Comment: It would be for the child of the flex container (`display: flex`). Would help if you could post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added code. I don't  use any children. Just style directly the td column Using the shown classes.